# Cannot read property 'cw' of null

Tags: javascript, exception, jsf, primefaces

When I receive an error in my application, I'm taken to a screen that interprets that error.

The problem is that the css on this screen is broken and I don't know what it can be.
The following messages appear on the browser console

```
Cannot read property 'cw' of null
Cannot read property of 'error' of null
Cannot read property of 'ab' of null
```

I'm using primefaces 7.0,
Java 8,
JSF 2.7

**My screen**
[image: Error screen without css]

**My errorTemplate.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
    template="/WEB-INF/errors/errorTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:param
        name="pageName"
        value="500" />
    <ui:param
        name="modenaColor"
        value="Red" />
    <ui:define name="content">
        <i class="icon-error Fs100 Red"></i>
        <div class="Wid100 OvHidden Fs30 Red">#{contentTitle}</div>
        <div class="Wid100 OvHidden Fs15 BoldGray">#{details}</div>
        <div class="EmptyBox20"></div>
        <div class="Separator"></div>
        <div class="EmptyBox10"></div>
        <div class="Container100 Fs18 White ContainerIndent">
            <div class="ui-fluid">
                <div class="Container33 Responsive ">
                    <div class="ContainerIndent">
                        <p:button
                            value="Início"
                            icon="fa fa-home"
                            styleClass="GreenButton RaisedButton"
                            outcome="home" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Container33 Responsive ">
                    <div class="ContainerIndent">
                        <p:button
                            value="Atualizar"
                            icon="fa fa-refresh"
                            onclick="location.reload(); return false;"
                            styleClass="OrangeButton RaisedButton" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Container33 Responsive ">
                    <div class="ContainerIndent">
                        <p:button
                            value="Detalhes"
                            icon="fa fa-code"
                            onclick="PF('details').toggle();return false;"
                            styleClass="RedButton RaisedButton" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="EmptyBox20"></div>
        <p:panel
            widgetVar="details"
            style="border:none;"
            styleClass="Wid100 TexAlLeft Fs10 BoldGray"
            collapsed="true"
            toggleable="true">
            <div class="OvAuto">
                <ui:insert name="errorContent">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Data/Hora: #{of:formatDate(now, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')}</li>
                        <li>User agent: #{header['user-agent']}</li>
                        <li>IP: #{empty header['x-forwarded-for'] ? request.remoteAddr : fn:split(header['x-forwarded-for'], ',')[0]}</li>
                        <li>URL: <a href="#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.request_uri']}">#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.request_uri']}</a></li>
                        <li>Ajax: #{facesContext.partialViewContext.ajaxRequest ? 'Sim' : 'Não'}</li>
                        <li>Código: #{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.status_code']}</li>
                        <li>Tipo: #{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception_type']}</li>
                        <li>Mensagem: #{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}</li>
                        <li>Stack trace: <pre class="Fs10">
                        <code>#{of:printStackTrace(requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception'])}</code>
                    </pre></li>
                    </ul>
                </ui:insert>
            </div>
        </p:panel>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**Finally my base.xhtml where is my generic html (Where it is present on all screens)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>
<h:outputStylesheet
        library="css"
        name="cookie.css" />
<ui:param
        name="pageName"
        value="#{empty pageName?'Gestão na nuvem':pageName}"/>
<ui:param
        name="stateless"
        value="#{empty stateless ? false : stateless}"/>
<ui:param
        name="modenaColor"
        value="${empty modenaColor ? 'Gray' : modenaColor}"/>

<f:view
        contentType="text/html"
        transient="#{stateless}"
        locale="pt">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta
                    http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
                    content="IE=edge"/>
            <meta
                    http-equiv="Content-Type"
                    content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <meta
                    name="viewport"
                    content="width=device-width,height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
            <meta
                    name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"
                    content="yes"/>
            <meta
                    http-equiv="pragma"
                    content="no-cache"/>
            <meta
                    http-equiv="Expires"
                    content="0"/>
            <meta
                    http-equiv="cache-control"
                    content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
            <meta
                    name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"
                    content="yes"/>
            <link
                    href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/favicon_blue.ico"
                    rel="shortcut icon"/>
        </f:facet>
        <title>e-Ceos - #{pageName}</title>
        <ui:insert name="head"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body onload="cookieController.loadLocalStorageCookieConsent()"
            class="${modenaColor}Modena Geometry"
            style="height: auto;">

    <p:outputPanel id="center">
        <p:outputPanel id="cookie">
            <p:outputPanel id="cookieBox">
            <span id="cookieText">
                 Este site armazena cookies para melhorar sua experiência. Para maiores informações consulte a nossa
                <a
                    class="link"
                    href="https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/e/2PACX-1vTxtAfe-jSf0qisY6U9X2E2XOlDS2sdMOM7lx0vuMUvLu0ThIorexwU2el4nCQNTozUmUMCBDIkFbUi/pub"
                    target="_blank">política de privacidade</a>.
            </span>
            <p:button
                    id="cookieBtn"
                    value="Aceito"
                    widgetVar="cookieBtn"
                    styleClass="RaisedButton GreenButton"
                    onclick="cookieController.saveLocalStorageCookieConsent()"/>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:outputPanel>

        <ui:insert name="body"/>
        <ui:insert name="pool">
            <h:form>
                <p:poll
                        interval="#{keepAliveController.keepAliveInterval}"
                        async="true"
                        ignoreAutoUpdate="true"
                        process="@this"
                        update="@this"
                        immediate="true"
                        listener="#{keepAliveController.keepAlive()}"/>
            </h:form>
        </ui:insert>
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{facesContext.application.projectStage ne 'Production'}">
            <ui:debug hotkey="X"/>
        </ui:fragment>

        <ui:fragment rendered="#{facesContext.application.projectStage eq 'Production'}">
            <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
            <script async='async' src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-64990319-3"></script>
            <script>
                  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                  gtag('js', new Date());
                
                  gtag('config', 'UA-64990319-3');


            </script>
        </ui:fragment>

        <!-- Chat do Movidesk -->
        <script type="text/javascript">var mdChatClient="#{commercialPartnerSupportController.widgetContent}";</script>
        <script src="https://chat.movidesk.com/Scripts/chat-widget.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Chat do Movidesk fim -->

        <o:deferredScript
                library="js"
                name="cookie.js" />
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

*Note*: When I refresh the screen, then the css is restored. Could it be some badly loaded js / css or some discontinued property in PF 7.0? I tried to look for something about it, but to no avail.

*Note²*: It seems to be a mojarra bug

Comment: Hmmm I don't usually put the h:head inside of F:view.  I didn't even know you could do that! And errors in your Chome F12 network browser about any files not being loaded or getting 404's?

Comment: Yes, some files in the head are not loaded other styles are not set, among other things

Comment: It's just a guess at this point - but it sounds to me like you might be breaking the life cycle or component tree somehow with your error handling - especially if a refresh solves it.

You would need to show the error handling that triggers this and what you are actually doing.

Comment: Hi Adam, sorry for the delay in responding, but i actually discover this bug, it seems to be a mojarra bug, for now i will try to update the mojarra's version